# Group numbers to make distance of any two numbers as large as possible

Tags: number-theory

I have a set of numbers ${\mathcal{ A}}=\{1,2,...,N\}$, I want to divide the set $ \mathcal{A}$ into $R$ equal sets, $\mathcal{\bar A}_i$, each of which has $N/R$ numbers. Now, I want to maximize the minimal distance of numbers in each set. How to divide the group and how many ways are there?

For example, when $N=4$, $R=2$, I can divide $\{1,2,3,4\}$ into $\{1,3\}$ and $\{2,4\}$ such that the minimal distance in each set is $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume there exists a configuration where the minimal distance is greater than $R$, i.e., it has to be at least $R+1$. Since $R\leq N$, then $R\in A$. Consider the set $S$ that contains the element $R$. Since we assumed the minimal distance to be at least $R+1$, then clearly $R$ is the minimal element in $S$. Now, the other elements in $S$ need to be at least $R+1$ apart, therefore, since we have $N/R$ elements  per set, the smallest values these elements can take would respectively have to be $\{R, 2R+1, 3R+2, \dots, \frac{N}{R}R+(R-1) \}$. The last element $\frac{N}{R}R + (R-1) = N+R-1\geq N$. So unless $R=1$, which is a trivial case, this cannot happen. So the minimal distance has to be $\leq R$.

It is easy to see that the configuration $$A_1=\{1, R+1, 2R+1, \dots, (\frac{N}{R}-1)R+1\},\\ \dots,\\ A_R=\{R, 2R, \dots, N\}$$ is a solution where the minimal distance is $R$. With a bit of work you should be able to show this is a unique solution (Hint: use $A_R$ and assume the distance between two consecutive elements is more than $R$).